# Issue in tensorflow 2 google colab tutorial

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I'm trying to follow the steps as dictated through this blog post https://medium.com/swlh/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-with-google-colab-b2af171e81cc. I have edited the pipeline.config file as mentioned on step 13. After which I tried to run it on colab. While executing the following line of code I get the error as

```
#Step 15- Train the model.

#run the cell to start model training 
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config
```

```
ValueError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to get matching files on pre-trained-models/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0: Not found: pre-trained-models/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint; No such file or directory
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you share your current directory structure and the content of pipeline.config. Without  this information it is hard to guess. Please update your question with the required files. The article might have overlooked an error or assumed it differently.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I rechecked my pipeline.config file and understood that I had made a mistake in specifying the correct pathname. I had written it as "pre_trained_model" but it should have been "pre-trained-model" !